# CakePHP - Both Ajax and URL in Link

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, hyperlink

I have this link that updates a field in the Database when clicked:

```
echo $this->Js->link('LinkToCallAjax', '/posts/visitCountUpdate/'.$post['Post']['post_id'], array('update' => 'visit_'.$post['Post']['post_id']), null, false);
```

and an anchor text that will go to a specified url.

How can i combine the 2 so that when I click the link it will update a field in the database and then go to the specified URL?

Already tried onclick(location.href) and it updated the database but got an error because cake is searching for the visitCountUpdate.ctp <- the function in the controller.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Two options: 1) have the db update on the controller action you're trying to go to anyway, 2) write your own jQuery to redirect when the ajax call is complete. See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Put your redirect in the function you want to execute and make the link a post link (that way there doesn't need to be anassociated .ctp file) - so you execute the method you wanted to do before and then redirect to an action that does have a .ctp file.

In your controller have:

```
public function SomeFunction($variableToPass) {
    //do something to do with the database (e.g. update records)
    return $this->redirect(
        array(
            'controller' => 'aController',
            'action' => 'anAction',
            $anotherVariableToPass
        )
    );
}
```

and then your link would be something like:

```
$this->Form->postLink(
    'Link Text',
    array(
        'controller' => 'posts',
        'action' => 'SomeFuntion',
        $variableToPass
    )
);
```